# ListView representation of List<string> inside a gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview, gridview

I have a listview inside a templatefield in an asp.net web application.

I need it to display the contents of a collection, 1 per row.

How can I do that?

[image: Current Design:]

I want the the table of the ListView to have multiple rows. 1 for each item in the list.
So for example:

```
Breeding Group | Breeding Group Role | Default

     AAA              1111                F
     BBB              2222                T
     CCC              3333                F
```

And that is for each 'Crop'

Is that possible?

Current Code:

Class:

```
[Serializable()]
public class UserCrops
{
    public UserCrops(string _Crop, List<string> _BG, List<string> _BGR, List<bool> _Default)
    {
        Crop = _Crop;
        BG = _BG;
        BGR = _BGR;
        Default = _Default;
    }
    public string Crop { get; set; }
    public List<string> BG { get; set; }
    public List<string> BGR { get; set; }
    public List<bool> Default { get; set; }
}
```

Binding:

```
    protected void GVUserCrops_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {

        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            ListView lv = (ListView)e.Row.FindControl("lvBGs");
            lv.DataSource = finalSelection;
            lv.DataBind();
        }
    }
```

GridView:

```
    <asp:GridView ID="GVUserCrops" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="4"
        ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" OnRowDataBound="GVUserCrops_RowDataBound"
        Width="634px">
        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Crop" HeaderText="Crop" />
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="BG/BGR">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:ListView ID="lvBGs" runat="server">
                        <LayoutTemplate>
                            <table style="border: solid 2px #336699;" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3" rules="all">
                                <tr style="background-color: #336699; color: White;">
                                    <th>
                                        Breeding Group
                                    </th>
                                    <th>
                                        Breeding Group Role
                                    </th>
                                    <th>
                                        Default
                                    </th>
                                </tr>
                                <tbody>
                                    <asp:PlaceHolder ID="itemPlaceHolder" runat="server" />
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </LayoutTemplate>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <%# Eval("BG")%>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <%# Eval("BGR")%>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <%# Eval("Default")%>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <AlternatingItemTemplate>
                            <tr style="background-color: #dadada;">
                                <td>
                                    <%# Eval("BG")%>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <%# Eval("BGR")%>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <%# Eval("Default")%>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </AlternatingItemTemplate>
                    </asp:ListView>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
        <EditRowStyle BackColor="#999999" />
        <FooterStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <PagerStyle BackColor="#284775" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" ForeColor="#333333" />
        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
        <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9E7E2" />
        <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#506C8C" />
        <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#FFFDF8" />
        <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6F8DAE" />
    </asp:GridView>
```

Edit:

Screenshot for list:
[image]

Edit2:

Sketch for what I am trying to accomplish.
[image]
[image]

Please excuse the crude drawings.
I am trying to get the list called finalSelection(in Sketch#1, 8 items) to appear like the Gridview in Sketch#2. Could probably do it much easier using cell spanning but seems like cheating.
So I made a gridview with 1 bound column 'Crop' and another column (templatecolumn)
I then put a listview control with a layout like a table(which i love)
Problem is when i assign listview.datasource to the finalSelection List is won't show like I am hoping (which seems logical)
What can i do to accomplish my goal? :)

Answer (score 1):

Replace the `<%# Eval("BG")%>` with `<%# Container.DataItem %>`

EDIT: After screen shot from OP.

Seems your DataSource is wrong. You are referring the class that the list is contained in.

Try this:

`lv.DataSource = finalSelection.BG;`

Comment: I was ready to kiss you but sadly all that resulted in was replace was to replace the System.Collections.Generic.List`1 with the name of the class 'UserAccess.UserCrops'

Comment: Weird, are you sure the strings in the list are not empty?

Comment: Yes, please check new screenshot.

Comment: BG is one of the 3 columns i wish to display

Comment: @AngelicCore Looking at your class and screen shot BG is a property of type List<String> not a value within the list.

Comment: Added sketches and more info :)